# Can i put URL rewriting http module in a folder?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I am trying to make a generic URL rewrite methods, and i want it portable so i checked this article: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx which is very nice.

But i want to put all my classes, http modules in one folder, then i can just paste this folder in any asp.net website and edit the web.config to point to this http module, thats it, without the need to add anything in the APP_Code as this article teaching.

My question is is that possible? any conc or better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET runtime only looks by default in a limited number of folders for code files that it compiles on the fly -- App_Code (and its subfolders) is one of them.  If you place code in an arbitrary folder, it won't be found.

The usual approach for what you describe is to build a DLL, and then drop it into the web site's bin folder.  You would then have a separate project in Visual Studio for building the DLL.  Using a subfolder in App_Code is another possibility.

You could also put your DLL into the GAC, which would make it accessible to all sites on a server.

Answer (score 2):

You always can to compile that code into an assembly (.dll), place it inside your /bin folder and to update your web.config file.